# Delete is not performed after an insertion - postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a function where I can store specific fields from a table before to delete the record, to keep an historical.

The insertion is working well, but the `Delete` sometimes is returning `Delete 0`, even if I have hardcode the `id` field that I want to delete.

This is my function:

```
create or replace function deletefromtable(_schema text, _table text, _filter text, _userid int)
returns json as
$func$
DECLARE _record json;
DECLARE target text;
DECLARE mykey TEXT;
DECLARE newvalue TEXT;
DECLARE oldvalue TEXT;
DECLARE columnname TEXT;

begin
    
    SET session_replication_role = replica;

    execute format ('select row_to_json(t) from (select * from ' || _schema ||'.' || _table || ' WHERE ' || _filter || ' ) t') into _record;

    raise notice 'record: %', _record;
    
    FOR target IN SELECT col from track_settings(_table) LOOP
    
        with vw_listing (new_record) as ( values 
            (_record::jsonb)
        )
        SELECT (new_record ->> target)::text INTO newvalue
        FROM vw_listing LIMIT 1;
        
        raise notice 'newvalue: %', newvalue;
        execute format ('insert into track_history (created_at, table_name, column_name, table_id, user_id, new_val, old_val, pg_user) 
                    values (''' || Now() || ''', ''' || _table || ''', ''' || target || ''', ''' || _filter || ''' ,' || _userid || ', null, ''' || newvalue || ''', current_user  )');
    
    END LOOP;
    
    execute ('DELETE FROM public.user WHERE id = 1 ;');  -- THIS LINE IS NOT EXECUTED
     
    SET session_replication_role = default;

    RETURN _record;
    
    COMMIT;

end
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

I tried to enable `SET session_replication_role = replica;` or `SET session_replication_role = default;` but is still not working.

The function hasn't any errors and is executing all the statements.
Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using ```session_replication_role``` at all?  The  delete ```execute``` does not have a ```format``` and the query is in ```()```. I would think you either need the ```format``` or lose the ```()```.

Comment: No, I'm not using any replication strategy or role @AdrianKlaver

Comment: ```SET session_replication_role = replica;``` in your function says you are at least attempting it. So again why? Also what about the ```execute``` line for the delete?

Comment: I just saw that in an example, I goingo to delete it @AdrianKlaver